# Creating zip file from byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

I'm sending byte string of a zip file from client side using `JSZip` and need to convert it back to zip on server side. the code I've tried isn't working.

```
b = bytearray()
b.extend(map(ord, request.POST.get("zipFile")))

zipPath = 'uploadFile' + str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.zip'
myzip = zipfile.ZipFile(zipPath, 'w') 
with  myzip:
    myzip.write(b)
```

It gives the error:

```
stat: path too long for Windows
```

How do I save my byte string as a zip file?

Comment: Are you _sure_ that the data returned from `request.POST.get("zipFile")` is a zipfile? In particular, are the first 4 bytes `b'PK\x03\x04'`? Also, you should mention whether you're using Python 2 or Python 3 (preferably by using the appropriate tag).

Comment: I used `zip.generateAsync({type:"base64"})` method from `JSZip` to convert the uploaded file to zip and get the byte string. Gotta trust the library to get it right, right? And I'm using Python 3

Comment: You'll likely want to decode that using `binascii.a2b_base64`.

Answer (score 11):

[`ZipFile.write(filename, [arcname[, compress_type]])`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write) takes the name of a local file to be added to the zip file. To write data from a `bytearray` or `bytes` object you need to use the [`ZipFile.writestr(zinfo_or_arcname, bytes[, compress_type])`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.writestr) method instead shown below:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(zipPath, 'w'):
    zipFile.writestr('name_of_file_in_archive', zipContents)
```

Note: if `request.POST.get("zipFile")` already is `bytes` (or `str` in python2) you don't need to convert it to a `bytearray` before writing it to the archive.

Answer (score 3):

JSZip already made a zip archive. The zipfile module is for accessing zip file contents, but you don't need to parse it to store it. In addition, bytearray can be created directly from strings so the map(ord,) is superfluous, and write can handle strings as well (bytearray is for handling numeric binary data or making a mutable stringlike object). So a slightly simplified variant might be:

```
zipContents = request.POST.get("zipFile")
zipPath = 'uploadFile' + str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.zip'
with open(zipPath, 'wb') as zipFile:
    zipFile.write(zipContents)
```

Comment: with a slight modification (` zipFile.write(bytes(zipContents, 'UTF-8')) `) it created the zip file but opening it gives error that the file is damaged.

Comment: I give up. I'll just compress the file from client side instead. Thanks.

Comment: What? I thought you already did, why else would you mention JSZip? Also, zip files aren't text and shouldn't use character encodings like UTF-8. They're binary data. Your `request` object might be important because of that; it likely has to decode the data from base64, urlescape or similar.